# Get an uploaded attachments local server path?

Tags: uploads

All the wordpress functions for retrieving media details seem to give you the web url of a file uploaded.  I want to the local server drive/folder path, ideally relative to the install of wordpress.  I have the attachment id value to hand so can parse that to a function, if only I knew what it was.

Is this possible with a function built in that I've missed?  If not does anyone have anything pre-written for this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`get_attached_file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) returns the server path of an attachment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'wp_upload_dir()' function to get an array of all the path information of the currently configured uploads directory.

Example:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upload_dir['path'];
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir